# Restricting input to a textbox in Visual Basic

Tags: vba, visual-studio-2012, textbox, conditional-formatting

I need to restrict a user to entering specific data into a text box. The requirements I have are:
1. The first character must be a lower case b or h.
2. Only accept letters after that.

---

I have code to only accept letters based on ascii equivalents, but do not know how to restrict only the first letter.

---

I would also accept entering that letter based on the selection of radio buttons, if I could restrict the user from editing the value.

I believe these can also be done using regular expressions, but have not had much experience with them.

```
Private Sub txtSysName_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtSysName.KeyPress
    If Asc(e.KeyChar) < 65 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 90 And Asc(e.KeyChar) < 97 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 122 Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Chris' suggestion, I used this, since the left and replace functions can no longer be used as they are in his answer as of vba 2010.

```
 If Not acro.Substring(1) = "u" Or Not acro.Substring(1) = "c" Then
        txtAcro.Text = acro.Replace(acro.Substring(1), "u")
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a check that would automatically change the first letter if it was not a b or h. Something like this:

```
If Not Left(TextBox.Text, 1) = "b" Or Not Left(TextBox.Text, 1) = "h" Then
    TextBox.Text = Replace(Left(TextBox.Text, 1), "b")
End If
```

That will replace the first letter with a 'b' if it isn't a b or h but you could just as easily display an error message if you would prefer.

Comment: Left is no longer an valid function in vb; had to use substring.